# Unable to build groovy release of resource_retriever

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any pointers as to what is wrong would be greatly appreciated...

Obtained package using wstool for desktop-full.
OS is debian:wheezy (raspberry pi)

==> cmake /.../catkin_ws/src/resource_retriever -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/.../devel_isolated/resource_retriever -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/groovy

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: ....

-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: ....

-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy

-- Found gtest sources under 'usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built

-- catkin 0.5.63

-- Could NOT find CURL (missing:  CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

CURL not found!  Aborting...

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (fail):

Unkown CMail command "fail".

=====

(Taken from CMakeLists.txt)

include(FindCURL)

if(NOT CURL_FOUND)

message("CURL not found!  Aborting...")

fail()

endif(NOT CURL_FOUND)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53684/unable-to-build-groovy-release-of-resource_retriever/) by [kurt.christofferson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4082/kurt.christofferson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-01-29**:
is there a specific reason why you want to build desktop-full?

**Comment by [kurt.christofferson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4082/kurt.christofferson/) on 2013-02-05**:
No.  New to ROS and am not sure what packages I will need.  This is a group of us and my task is to get the full to build on pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend starting with the desktop package and go from there. Setting up ROS full does not make too much sense because the RasPi will be too slow for most visualization. There is a tutorial on how to set up groovy [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source)

It also provides an iso you can dd on your SD card so you can get started right away

I would recommend joining the [ROS SIG embedded](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/ros-sig-embedded)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0